# A strange spam with a mistake in a word on my website

Tags: spam

I have an ads board. About one year ago I started to get a strange spam via ContactUs and SendMessage forms. Both forms have a CAPTCHA code. The IP addresses are very different: Asya, Africa, South America, North America, Europe ... ... The email address which is indicated has a real domain. The messages consist of one phrase and at least one word has an mistake. I'm getting about 10-30 messages during a day (not all-at-once) and all messages and IP addresses are different.
Here are several samples (Name, email address, IP address, message):

Lily, mlittman@cs.br, 188.143.232.12, Kewl you shluod come up with that. Excellent!

Priya, helpdesk@earthlightsjewelry.com, 95.211.171.55, Deadly accurate answer. You've hit the blulseye!

Surya, nsaussier@fightaidsmonaco.com, 83.133.110.36, I was really confused, and this answered all my qsuteions.

Franklin, mariajames@tiscali.it, 189.2.186.102, Cheers pal. I do appcreatie the writing.

Tomblok, oswapini@seznam.cz, 92.96.222.230, Pefrect answer! That really gets to the heart of it!

Safdar, schuhmacher@nabu-hamburg.de, 188.143.232.12, People normally pay me for this and you are giinvg it away!

Tony, groups@yankees.com, 83.133.110.36, What a pleasure to find someone who thinks through the isseus

Rock, 20ramonrevilla@hotmail.com, 188.143.232.12, Thank God! Someone with brains spakes!

Saya, claire@claireanderson.com, 83.133.110.36,

Serginho, libr@stgvs.tpc.edu.tw, 98.216.34.115,I really apprceitae free, succinct, reliable data like this.

What is this? Who is sending, a human or machines? Why? How? How to protect the forms?

Thanks!

Comment: 95.211.171.55 points to - `https://donbot.shweppsie.com/`. donbot - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donbot_botnet.

Comment: Nearly all ip-s have a simple `It works` default apache page.

Comment: http://www.mma-core.com/videos/fights/Elaina_Maxwell_vs_Miesha_Tate_Strikeforce_10_LQ_22/10000577. Look at the comments - the same nonsense: - `I really apprceitae free, succinct, reliable data like this.`

Comment: I will try to make captcha stronger...

Comment: I had this kind of spam for a while on one of my blogs. I believe the spammer is using the words with the mistakes to track the success of his spam efforts.

Comment: @reggie: [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) has two words:  an obfuscated known word and an unknown word that Google is trying to crowdsource the [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition "optical character recognition") for.  It therefore makes a lot of sense that only one word would ever be correct given OCR-based captcha bots.

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be to make sure that your software is up to date.  It could be that the spammers have found some way through your captcha (this is rather common, actually) and that the software you're using has an update that fixes this waiting for you to install.  If the software you're using hasn't had any updates in several months, consider migrating to software that is more actively maintained.

Some CMS software allow requiring moderator approval.  This would reduce the spam significantly, and only you would see it (since you'd never approve it).  This is more work for you, but most spammers won't even try if they get properly warned.

Another option is to increase the difficulty of your captchas (as you mentioned above) or introduce additional requirements before posting.  One good one is account creation with email verification.  Few spammers will go to that length to post on your site, especially if you're also using [nofollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_in_blogs#nofollow) (which removes the benefit to spamming: no PageRank increase).

Finally, you could try to work around the problem yourself.  It sounds like you have bot-spam coming in from open proxies or compromised web servers.  Since real users tend not to surf the web *from* web servers, you could perform a quick test that increases the captcha difficulty (or even blocks posting) on any IP that has port 80 opened.

There may or may not be spam detection extensions for your site's software.  I've seen URI DNSBL checkers (which will block known bad sites from posts) and even Bayesian spam detection (trainable content filters).

Answer (score 0):

A newest automatic spam software (like xrumer for example) can automatic recognize any captcha (and recaptcha) code. If you want more serious spam protection - use [uniqpin.com](http://uniqpin.com)